# Collection View reordering cells upon return to view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, uicollectionview

I currently have a collection view set up to display a dynamic number of objects in its view. Each cell displays an image from the corresponding object. When a cell is tapped, it triggers a segue to the next view in the hierarchy. The cell's corresponding object is passed to the next view However, I am noticing that when I return the view with the collection, the ordering of cells has changed, and now, when I tap one to got the next view, its properties are from objects of other cells.

Below are my methods of the UICollectionView:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsCount
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Chow Object Reuse ID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)

    //Since loading of images is a time-intensive task, all the thumbnails 
    //may have not been fetched yet.
    if (imageThumbsArray.count == objectsCount) { //Eventually, a more elegant fix will be needed.
        imageView.image = imageThumbsArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.objectToBePassed = self.chowObjectsArray[indexPath.row] as PFObject
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Show Chow Details", sender: self)
}
```

I also call `self.PastObjectsCollection.reloadData()`
Why is the reordering and mixing up of cells happening?

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: I don't know about the reordering, but you have another problem. Each time cellForItem is called you will be adding new image views to the cells. You either need to remove them first, before you add them, check if they exist and add them only if they don't, or, what I think is the best solution, add the image views in the init method for a custom cell (or make the cell in IB).

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? I very new to iOS programming.
Also, the number of objects is dynamic and I can't predict it, so I don't think I will be able to do that in IB.